# Core Data crash: NSInvalidArgumentException keypath count not found in entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
+ (NSArray *)retrievePercent{
    NSArray *percentResult = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NTSmartRegionGPS MR_createFetchRequest];
    
    NSString *entityName = [NTSmartRegionGPS MR_entityName];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    //The query result displays the corresponding ssid value
    NSAttributeDescription *compactKeyDesc = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"compactKey"];
    
    //Sum ssid columns
    NSExpression *compactKeyExpn = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"compactKey"];
    NSExpression *countExpn = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"count:" arguments:@[compactKeyExpn]];
    NSExpressionDescription *countExpnDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    countExpnDesc.name = @"count";
    countExpnDesc.expression = countExpn;
    //TODO Using NSInteger32AttributeType will cause the percentage resolution value to be abnormal, and the reason to be investigated
    countExpnDesc.expressionResultType = NSStringAttributeType;
    
    //The method is as follows: count() * 100/countOfEntity
    //(It is found in the actual measurement that the division result will be rounded. To get the proportion, multiply by 100 first)
    NSUInteger countOfEntity = [NTSmartRegionGPS MR_countOfEntities];
    if (countOfEntity <= 0) {
        return percentResult;
    }
    NSExpression *multiplierValueExpn = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@(100)];
    NSExpression *multiplyExpn = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"multiply:by:" arguments:@[countExpn, multiplierValueExpn]];
    NSExpression *sumValueExpn = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@(countOfEntity)];
    NSExpression *divideExpn = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"divide:by:" arguments:@[multiplyExpn, sumValueExpn]];
    NSExpressionDescription *percentExpnDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    percentExpnDesc.name = @"percent";
    percentExpnDesc.expression = divideExpn;
    //TODO Using NSInteger32AttributeType will cause the percentage resolution value to be abnormal, and the reason to be investigated
    percentExpnDesc.expressionResultType= NSStringAttributeType;
    
    
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[compactKeyDesc, countExpnDesc, percentExpnDesc];
    fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"compactKey"];
    //Use count results to sort in descending order
    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"count" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sd];
    @try {
        percentResult = [NTSmartRegionGPS MR_executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException keypath count not found in entity NTSmartRegionGPS
        DDLogError(@"Fetch gps region percent fail, exception:%@", exception.reason);
    }
    return percentResult;
}
```

[image]

NTSmartRegionGPS is an NSManagedObject object that inherits from CoreData.
The above function implements group summation of records in the database, and then calculates the percentage.

Monitoring records by Crash shows the following lines will Crash：

```
percentResult = [NTSmartRegionGPS MR_executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
```

Crash info: Fatal Exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath count not found in entity '

This code is tested in my iPhone12(real machine), it can output the percentage result normally (when the database is empty/with single data/with multiple data), so I don't know why the user(%1-%2) will encounter Crash.

Could anybody give a hand?;)

Comment: Without knowing the Core Data model there's no *hand to take* . But the error *keypath count not found* is pretty significant, maybe just a misspelling of an attribute name.

Comment: This code is tested in my local real machine, it can output the percentage result normally (when the database is empty/with single data/with multiple data), so I don't know why the user will encounter Crash.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting key in a `NSSortDescriptor` of a `NSFetchRequest` must be part of the Core Data Entity in the model.

In case you don't use the fetch request with a `NSFetchedResultController`, you can also use a computed property in the custom class of the entity as sorting key. This custom class must be registered as such in the Core Data model.